# How do you configure pyChecker to read from a string?

Tags: python, pychecker

I am trying to get pyChecker to check the syntax of a string.

```
s="""
print "hi"
print "hello"
print 3/0
"""
```

Is there anyway I can do this, I was trying to change the source code of pyChecker to read a string but it is too confusing. I could be missing a built in way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/):

> PyChecker works in a combination of ways. First, it imports each
>   module. If there is an import error, the module cannot be processed.

Since `import` does quite a bit of work under the covers, including a full compilation pass that PyChecker needs to do its tricks, my guess is that you'd do far, far better writing `s` to a file. The alternative would reinvent some complicated wheels.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to do this with pyFlakes or pyLint, I was looking at the code for both and they are pretty complicated